# Serializing content items - issue with childrenOfPath

Tags: unicorn

We ran into a strange issue while setting up serialization for our content tree in a Sitecore 9.2 XP0 environment. Our goal is to achieve a configuration that serializes a **skeleton** of our content tree and is deployed once when ever it does not exist or another developer added new top-level folders.

**Our issue is:** childrenOfPath rules are not applied correctly. The entire content tree within */Global* is serialized despite excluding it or ignoring it completely.
I've attached a screenshot of our content tree as well as two configurations. One working. One not working.

The configuration you see below is our attempt to a more generic approach which fails to exclude the children of the */Global* folder.
Additionally I've tried to remove the `\` from name at the except element as well as played around with the includeChildren attribute.

```
   <configuration name="Project.Foo.DeployOnce" description="Foo Global Content" dependencies="Foundation.*,Feature.*,Project.Common" extends="Foo.Project">
          <evaluator type="Unicorn.Evaluators.NewItemOnlyEvaluator, Unicorn" singleInstance="true"/>
          <predicate>
            <include name="Foo Tenant" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/Foo">
              <exclude childrenOfPath="Global">
                <except name="\*" includeChildren="false"/>
              </exclude>
            </include>
          </predicate>
          <rolePredicate>
            <include domain="extranet" pattern="^Project Foo Global.*$" />
          </rolePredicate>
     </configuration>
```

This works and meets the requirement of only serializing the needed skeleton folders but is not generic and requires developers to manually add to the configuration ( and also remember to do so )

```
   <configuration name="Project.Foo.DeployOnce" description="Foo Global Content" dependencies="Foundation.*,Feature.*,Project.Common" extends="Foo.Project">
          <evaluator type="Unicorn.Evaluators.NewItemOnlyEvaluator, Unicorn" singleInstance="true"/>
          <predicate>
            <include name="Foo Tenant" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/Foo">
              <exclude children="true">
                <except name="Global" />
                <except name="Global/Site Settings" />
                <except name="Global/Module Content" />
                <except name="Global/Module Content/Gallery" />
                <except name="Global/Module Content/Image" />
                <except name="Global/Module Content/Media Text" />
                <except name="Global/Module Content/Youtube Video" />
              </exclude>
            </include>
          </predicate>
          <rolePredicate>
            <include domain="extranet" pattern="^Project Foo Global.*$" />
          </rolePredicate>
     </configuration>
```

Do I have a wrong understanding of how childrenOfPath works? I feel like I've developed a tunnel vision.

[image]
[image: Content tree that needs serialization]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you are making this so complicated.

```
<include name="Foo Tenant" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/Foo">
    <exclude path="/sitecore/content/Foo/Global" />
</include>
```

Should do the trick, if I'm reading your question correctly.

For reference configurations I always recommend looking to the official Test Configuration set. https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn.Tests/Predicates/TestConfiguration.xml#L7

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I do wish to exclude all items in the Global folder except those within the red box but exclude their child items. Basically I'm looking for something like a "depth" attribute to use. The second XML should clarify what I want to have included in the serialization.

Comment: You're going down a rabbit hole :-)   Split it up into two predicates.  One that completely ignores the Global item (like above), and one that puts the scaffolding in place under it. Make the second predicate have a dependency on the first, so you still get your "Foo" tenant item.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I was determined to try to force it all into a single configuration. Splitting it up like you suggested worked wonders. :)

Comment: I know where you're coming from, it's an easy mistake to make :-)   There will be some changes coming to predicates in the nearer future which might make some of this easier - but for now it's definitely my recommendation to split things up a bit. Also makes the configuration much easier to read and understand :-)